# What is the best translated Telugu version to understand Vedas as it is in sanskrit?

Tags: vedas, telugu

I'm very much interested to know and understand the vedas. I'm Telugu student. So I can understand Telugu versions. Please help me.. It's been  1 year I'm searching for the answer in every platform available in internet. Please help me or guide me.

Comment: @hanugm what's the need of the tag 'telugu'? do we have tag for 'english' or 'hindi'?

Comment: @YDS It will be helpful for searching translations for a particular language. Since English the the language for site, there is no need. But, Hindi or other languages in which scriptures has been translated can be okay to do so. Do you disagree?

Answer (score 1):

A Partial answer.

---

You can find Rig Veda in Telugu at the following link.

https://sanskritdocuments.org/telugu/rigveda/

Meaning of Rig Vedic mantras can be seen at the following link.

https://www.indiadivine.org/content/files/file/188-rig-veda-in-telugu-pdf/

---

KRISHNA YAJURVEDA SAMHITHA TELUGU is available at the following link.

https://archive.org/details/KYVTS11Telugu001_20150606

Meaning of Sukla Yajur Veda mantras in Telugu is available at the following link.

https://www.indiadivine.org/content/files/file/189-yajur-veda-in-telugu-pdf/

---

Sama Veda is a liturgical text which consists of 1,549 verses. ***All but 75 verses*** have been taken from the Rigveda.

A word of caution:

A mere reading of Rig Veda does not give the depth of meaning the mantra therein contain.  It is advisable to have guidance of a good scholar.